# Build data constructor using generics in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How to construct a value by given constructor name and constructor arguments. For example, having the following data type

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

data Test = Foo | Bar Int | Baz String Int deriving (Generic, Show)
```

I would have such function

```
make "Foo" -- > Foo
make "Bar" 1 -- > Bar 1
make "Baz" "hi" 777 -- > Baz "hi" 777
```

The solution in [this article](https://ocharles.org.uk/posts/2014-04-26-constructing-generically.html) is pretty close, but it works for data types only with single data constructor.

**EDIT**

So why do I want to do this? I have a BERT-encoded data that comes from the client. I can decode it to the `Term`s from the [bert package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bert). I want to have something like this

```
case x of
  Foo -> do something
  Bar x -> do something with x
```

and so on instead of

```
case x of
  TupleTerm y ->
    case y of
      [AtomTerm "foo"] -> do something
      [AtomTerm "bar", IntTerm x] -> do something with x
```

**EDIT2**

I concluded, that I was going in the wrong way.

Comment: Well the problem with this is: what would the signature of the `make` function be? `String -> Test`, `String -> Int -> Test`? `String -> String -> Int -> Test`?

Comment: I don't know, may be some type-level magic will help?

Comment: well even if that was possible, then how would you process this? What would the type of `make some_string` be? Since it depends on the *value* of `some_string`, it has no specific value, hence type contracts could no longer get satisfied.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have a BERT encoded data, that comes from the web browser, and I'm trying to turn it into the plain Haskell values. It is annoying to match BERT `Term`s every time.

Comment: Now I think there should be a better way for such transformations. I.e. `transform :: (Generic t, FromBert (Rep t)) => Term -> Maybe t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I have a BERT encoded data, that comes from the web browser"

There is not a reasonable way to solve the problem as you have posed it.  However, if you are parsing data and you want to turn it into a Haskell data structure, the place to select the constructor is within the parser.  Something like:

```
make :: Parser Test
make = do
  tag <- parse string
  case tag of
    "Foo" -> Foo
    "Bar" -> Bar <$> int
    "Baz" -> Baz <$> string <*> int

sting :: Parser String
int   :: Parser Int
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I want to do this in a generic way.